# SquidCoin.cs My Currency Script is not working after adding [PlayerPrefs]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a currency script for my game that is not displaying how much money the user has.

It was working before I added the PlayerPrefs class.
But after the addition, it will not display anything.

FYI, the PlayerPrefs class allows me to display numbers across multiple scenes in Unity.

I have posted my code below

```
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.UI;

public class squidCoin : MonoBehaviour {


public Text coinDisplay;
public int addMoneyAmmount;
public int squidCoins;
public float saveInterval;
public float paycheckTime;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
squidCoins = 50;
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SquidCoins", squidCoins);
 StartCoroutine(moneyADD());
 StartCoroutine("SaveMoney");


  }

public void squidCoinPayCheck(int squidCoinsToAdd){
    squidCoins += squidCoinsToAdd;

  }

  public void Awake(){
  PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SquidCoinsSaves");
  }

public void minusSquidCoin(int squidCoinsToSubtract){
if(squidCoins - squidCoinsToSubtract < 0){
        Debug.Log ("Oops Hes Broke");
        squidCoins += addMoneyAmmount;
    }
    else{
    squidCoins -= squidCoinsToSubtract;
    }

}


  IEnumerator moneyADD(){
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(paycheckTime);
     squidCoins += addMoneyAmmount;
 }

 IEnumerator SaveMoney (){
     while (true)
     {
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(saveInterval);
             PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SquidCoinSaves", squidCoins);

     }
 }


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
 coinDisplay.text = "You Have: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SquidCoinsSaves");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i looked at all of your code and it seems there is have many wrong details. I just fixed it and noted your wrongs with comment in front of the wrong parts

```
using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.UI;

public class squidCoin : MonoBehaviour {


public Text coinDisplay;
public int addMoneyAmmount;
public int squidCoins;
public float saveInterval;
public float paycheckTime;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
squidCoins = 50;
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SquidCoinsSaves", squidCoins); //your string name was wrong
 StartCoroutine(moneyADD());
 StartCoroutine("SaveMoney");


  }

public void squidCoinPayCheck(int squidCoinsToAdd){
    squidCoins += squidCoinsToAdd;

  }

  public void Awake(){
  //PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SquidCoinsSaves"); //you can not get it like this, first you must equal this ti intiger type varible
  }

public void minusSquidCoin(int squidCoinsToSubtract){
if(squidCoins - squidCoinsToSubtract < 0){
        Debug.Log ("Oops Hes Broke");
        squidCoins += addMoneyAmmount;
    }
    else{
    squidCoins -= squidCoinsToSubtract;
    }

}


  IEnumerator moneyADD(){
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(paycheckTime);
     squidCoins += addMoneyAmmount;
 }

 IEnumerator SaveMoney (){
     while (true)
     {
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(saveInterval);
             PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SquidCoinsSaves", squidCoins); //string name was wrong

     }
 }


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
 coinDisplay.text = "You Have: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SquidCoinsSaves");
}
}
```

Comment: But everything else is SquidCoinSaves plus it did not work

Comment: @ThunderCloud look at my answer again

Comment: what do you mean by: you can not get it like this, first you must equal this ti intiger type varible